# Problemas com api restfull

Tags: java, json

Tenho uma API *Restfull* no servidor Apache local que retorna uma lista de usuários do banco de dados (localhost/api/usuarios).

Estou utilizando o site [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) para validar meu JSON. Quando acesso via *browser* eu pego o resultado e valido no JSONLint, o qual me retorna como JSON válida. Um exemplo retornado pela API:

```
{
    "usuarios": [
        {
            "id": 167,
            "contrato": 1,
            "cod": "1212",
            "nome": "Marcos Roberto Pavesi",
            "email": "marcos@p.com.br",
            "senha": "114fdfefd3d69799f0b6f73ef764d405",
            "ativo": "S",
            "setor": "1",
            "max_add": "",
            "dealer": 0
        },
        {
            "id": 520,
            "contrato": 1,
            "cod": "",
            "nome": "avaliador",
            "email": "avaliador@teste.com.br",
            "senha": "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e",
            "ativo": "S",
            "setor": "2",
            "max_add": "",
            "dealer": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Entretanto, estou tentando acessar minha aplicação via Java seguindo [essa explicação](http://theoryapp.com/parse-json-in-java/) e estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: 
>   A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
>   
>   at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:433)
>   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:197)
>   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:324)
>   at com.main.Main.main(Main.java:14)

Estou acessando a api com o seguinte código...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("http://localhost:8080/api_carmaix/api/usuarios");
        JSONArray arr = null;
        try {
                arr = obj.getJSONArray("usuarios");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }




            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
            {            
                System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id")); 

            }
}
```

}

Comment: @renan editei.. entretanto você poderia me passar o seu código? Obrigado.

Comment: Eu tinha feito um código pra testar o `JSONObject`, nada de mais. Quando editou a pergunta ficou mais claro qual é o problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenha em mente que as classes desse pacote não fazem requisições.
Elas fazem o *parse* de alguma fonte (`String`, `Map`, ...) e permitem que você manipule o objeto como um JSON.

Seu código lança uma `JSONException` porque é [esperado uma string iniciada por "`{`"](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONObject.java#L312-L326) e você está passando uma url.

Você precisa dividir as coisas: Primeiro fazer a requisição para obter a resposta da sua API — e aqui não precisa ser nada complexo, pode obter a resposta como uma string mesmo. Depois que tiver a resposta em mãos, você cria um `JSONObject` e passa essa string como argumento para o construtor.

Pode criar um método que busque o JSON em uma url:

```
public String getJSON(String url){
    String data = null;

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();

        if(connection.getResponseCode() == 200){
            try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))){
                String line;
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                while((line = buff.readLine()) != null)
                    builder.append(line);
                data = builder.toString();
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception err){
        // Algum tratamento :)
    }
    return data;
}
```

Tendo esse método, você pode chamá-lo passando a URL que sua API devolve o JSON com os usuários. E o retorno, pode passar no construtor do `JSONObject`:

```
// Resposta da API
String data = getJSON("http://localhost:8080/api_carmaix/api/usuarios");

if (data != null) {
    try {
       // Usando a resposta da API para criar um objeto JSON:
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject(data);

       JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("usuarios");
       for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
           System.out.println("ID: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getInt("id"));

    } catch (Exception err) {}
}
```

Veja também que ao percorrer o `JSONArray` utilizei `getInt` ao invés de `getString` como você está utilizando. Se tentar pegar o valor de "id" como string uma `JSONException` também será lançada contendo a mensagem:

> JSONObject["id"] not a string.